# The type or namespace name 'Nmo' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management'

Tags: c#, sql-server, dll, namespaces

i tried to load a project but it said:

```
The type or namespace name 'Nmo' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management'
```

i only know a Smo dll but Nmo? where to find that?

**UPDATE:**
i added the smo dll of the 2008 version... but it still giving out the error... maybe, i should get the smo dll of the sql 2005 version? coz the machine where i got this project is using sql 2005

Comment: wow... you're probably right.. the machine where i got this is using sql server 2005, i am using 2008....hmmm... where could i get that dll?

Comment: i added the smo dll of the 2008 version... but it still giving out the error... maybe, i should get the smo dll of the sql 2005 version? coz the machine where i got this project is using sql 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from an article titled *"[Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Notification Services](http://flylib.com/books/en/4.214.1.123/1/)"*:

> **NMO API Assemblies and Namespaces**
>
> To use the NMO API, applications must reference the assemblies that contain the needed classes. The following two assemblies are usually required:
>
> - Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
> - Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
>
> The first assembly, Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll , contains most of the classes in the SMO Framework, including the NMO classes (there isn't a separate NMO assembly). The Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll contains utility classes used to establish database connections. Classes from both assemblies are typically needed in programs that use the NMO API.
>
> Most of the classes you'll encounter while working with NMO are defined in one of the following three namespaces:
>
> - Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Nmo
> - Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo
> - Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common
>
> The first one is sometimes referred to as the NMO namespace . It contains all the NMO-specific classes. The second namespace contains many of the SMO classes, some of which are needed in NMO programming. The third namespace contains common utility classes, such as those used to establish database connections.

**EDIT:**

[Take a look here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15748), search for *"Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Management"* and download the appropriate DLL. I unzipped it and it appears to contain a Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo file. When I tried to install it, I got a message instructing me to [download a prerequisite](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54583) (the SQL Server Native Client), and the page it directed me to appears to be an updated version of the 2005 DLLs, so you may just want to use the DLLs from that page.

Also, as a side note, if you're actually connecting to a 2008 SQL Server, you should be able to use the 2005 DLL to manage it, but the newer "2008-specific" features will not be available using the older DLL.

Comment: i added the smo dll of the 2008 version... but it still giving out the error... maybe, i should get the smo dll of the sql 2005 version? coz the machine where i got this project is using sql 2005

Comment: its ok... my problem now is where i could get that smo sql 2005 version

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Nmo namespace contains classes that are used to develop and administer Notification Services instances and applications.
Here is link for more info
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.nmo%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

You need to add "microsoft.sqlserver.smo.dll" assembly reference

Comment: i added the smo dll of the 2008 version... but it still giving out the error... maybe, i should get the smo dll of the sql 2005 version? coz the machine where i got this project is using sql 2005